# Emulating aspx form requests with python

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, python-requests

i am trying to emulate work of aspx form from this site - http://noidajalonline.com/NOIDAJAL/Consumer.aspx

But have some problem - in first post request which response should contain values for one of select elements in form. For some reason i get this text in response - '0|error|500||'.

Why this thing happens? Also here's the screenshot of same request when i trying to use this aspx form from browser - http://puu.sh/kfcN1/c7b3b991fb.png
And here's my code: (its python 2 but i think it should run with python 3 too).

```py
#! python2
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

s = requests.Session()

main_search_html = s.get('http://www.noidajalonline.com/NOIDAJAL/Consumer.aspx').text
main_search = fromstring(main_search_html)
view_state = main_search.xpath('//input[@name="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value')[0]
event_validation = main_search.xpath('//input[@name="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value')[0]

payload = {
    'ctl00$ScriptManager1' :     'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlsector',
    '__EVENTTARGET' : 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlsector',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
    '__LASTFOCUS' : '',
    '__VIEWSTATE' : view_state,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : event_validation,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlsector' : '01',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtflatno' : '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCons_no' : '',
    '__ASYNCPOST' : 'true',
}

post = s.post('http://www.noidajalonline.com/NOIDAJAL/Consumer.aspx', data = payload)
print(post.text) # Here i've got an error in response '0|error|500||'
```

Comment: better to use mechanize

Comment: Yeah, thats more simple way but its much slower.

Answer (score 0):

That was so simple! This aspx form just requires 'User-Agent' in request header.
So, i just changed one of lines to this:

```
post = s.post('http://www.noidajalonline.com/NOIDAJAL/Consumer.aspx', data = payload, headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
```